# Interpretation of function notation

Tags: notation

Consider the following statements, seen in this order in a paper ("An equilibrium characterization of the term structure" by Vasicek (1977)):

(1) "Let $P(t,s)$ denote the price."

(2) (after some assumption is made), "...this implies the price $P(t,s)$ is a function of $r(t)$, $P(t,s) = P(t,s,r(t))$."

Before statement (2), what should I be thinking of $P$ as, a function or some number?  I.e, by the use of the author's notation $P(t,s)$, should I perhaps think of $P$ as $P: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to [0,\infty)$ (say)?  But then, when he actually states **it is a function** of $r(t)$, what should I think of $P$ as?  Either $P: (\text{range of $r$}) \to [0,\infty)$ or $P: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times (\text{range of } r) \to [0,\infty)$?

Right now I'm going with the latter, and so I read statement (2) as, "we've already defined $P$ to be a function of $(t,s)$, but by some assumption we've made $P$ is *really* also a function of $r(t)$."  Is this correct?

Comment: What paper is this (or at least what area)?

Comment: It certainly doesn't hurt to assume the latter.  If $t$ and $s$ aren't otherwise used individually you could just think of the function as mapping $f(s, t, z)=f(z)$ just ignoring the $s$ and the $t$.

Comment: @mrf I added the title of the paper, but I can't find a link online.  I only have a pdf myself.